# Where/how to include helper methods for capybara integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I"m using capybara for my integration/acceptance tests. They're in `/spec/requests/` folder. Now I have a few helper methods that I use during acceptance tests. One example is `register_user` which looks like this

```
def register_user(user)
  visit home_page
  fill_in 'user_name', :with => user.username
  fill_in 'password', :with => user.password
  click_button 'sign_up_button'
end
```

I want to use this method in several different acceptance tests (they're in different files). What's the best way to include this? I've tried putting it in `spec/support/` but it hasn't been working for me. After spending some time on it I realized I don't even know if it's a good way of doing it so I figured I'd ask here.

Note: I am using rails 3, spork and rspec.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Put your helper to the spec/support folder and do something like this:

*spec/support/:*

```
module YourHelper
  def register_user(user)
    visit home_page
    fill_in 'user_name', :with => user.username
    fill_in 'password', :with => user.password
    click_button 'sign_up_button'
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include YourHelper, :type => :request
end
```

Comment: When do you use spec/support vs. spec/helpers?

Comment: @cman77 spec/helpers is for testing app/helpers, spec/support files are for modules and configuration that you want to use in you specs

Comment: Aren't all the files inside spec/support loaded automatically?

Comment: @Gerep `spec/support` is loaded automatically. But that doesn't make the helper available to RSpec automatically.

Comment: That's an adding a helper to RSpec, not Capybara.

Comment: spec/support is no longer loaded automatically, there's a commented-out line in the `spec_helper.rb` that can be used to include the files in the support directory: `Dir[Rails.root.join('spec', 'support', '**', '*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`

Answer (score 16):

I used the given solution by @VasiliyErmolovich, but I changed the type to make it work:

```
config.include YourHelper, :type => :feature
```

Comment: Same here ... that's if you have your test in spec/features vs. spec/requests

Answer (score 0):

Explicit way with ruby

Using `include`:

```
# spec/support/your_helper.rb
class YourHelper
  def register_user(user)
    visit home_page
    fill_in 'user_name', :with => user.username
    fill_in 'password', :with => user.password
    click_button 'sign_up_button'
  end
end

describe MyRegistration do
  include YourHelper

  it 'registers an user' do
    expect(register_user(user)).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Comment: Alright, this isolates the helper from other tests. But what if it's a Capybara/Selenium-specific helper that is commonly needed? Like some wrapper around JS that I'll need in all my test files. And that I don't want to call it via `MyHelpers::my_js_helper` but I want it to be as easily accessible as `find`.

Comment: @Nakilon it's plain ruby, you can refactor your specs/code/DSL/capybara/selenium/whatever with it. Because everywhere `include` works like mixin. `Find` method already exists in capybara. But it doesn't prevent to create another method e.g. `content_find` using mixin approach.

Comment: RSpec's [`include`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/5e395e2016f1da19475e6db2817eb26dae828c4c/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1359) and [`exclude`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/5e395e2016f1da19475e6db2817eb26dae828c4c/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb#L1437) -- while they look like plain Ruby they are in fact customly defined for a filtering ability and maybe even something more. While there is [no "def include"](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/search?q=%22def+include%22&unscoped_q=%22def+include%22) in Capybara repo, maybe there is something else I don't know.

Comment: Oh, I'm wrong here. Inside the `describe` the `include` method is plain Ruby. But the problem still remains that I'll need to put this line in every context I need, in dozens of files.