# How to include/set visible helper methods for rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rspec, visibility, helper

I use a method named "**generate_coordinate**" (located in the app/helpers/planets_helper.rb) in my controller **PlanetsController**.

When running tests, it seems that rspec isn't able to access it, and so cause my test suite to fail because the planet doesn't have any coordinates.

I tried to include my helper at the beginning of the **utilities.rb** file, but it didn't work

```
include ApplicationHelper
include PlanetsHelper
```

I also tried to **write my method inside the utilities.rb file**, without more success.

I read this post "[Where/how to include helper methods for capybara integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192559/where-how-to-include-helper-methods-for-capybara-integration-tests)", but it didn't help me.

I also read about "stub" functions, but because I can't understand what it could be used for, it didn't help me much...

Any idea ?

---

Here is my **test code** (spec/requests/planet_pages_spec.rb)

```
describe "Create planet" do
    before do
        visit new_planet_path
        fill_in "Name", with: "MyPlanet"
        click_button "Validate"
    end

    it {should have_selector('h1', text: "Planet")}
end
```

When click on "Validate", it leads to the **PlanetsController**, which calls the "generate_coordinate" method

```
def create
    @planet = Planet.new(name: params[:planet][:name],
        coordinates: generate_coordinates, [...])

        if @planet.save
            redirect_to action: 'index'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
```

And here is the generate_coordinate method, which seems never been called by rspec (whereas it is when I navigate through with my browser)

```
module PlanetsHelper

    def generate_coordinates
        coordinates = "0.0.0.0"
    end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `generate_coordinate` method is used by both your controller and helper, consider moving into your controller (as a private method) and adding this one-liner to allow views and helpers to access it:

```
# planets_controller.rb
helper_method :generate_coordinate
```

`helper_method` exposes controller methods to views and helpers within the scope of the controller (in this case, planets#index, planets#show, etc).

If you'd rather do it the other way round you have two options:

- insert `include PlanetsHelper` at the top of the controller (under `class PlanetsController`)
- when you want to call the helper method, call it like this: `view_context.generate_coordinate(...)`

Try them out and see which one suits your needs best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Zubin. It is not yet really clear for me about what portion of code is visible by what other portion of code. For example: every method in MycontrollerHelper should be automaticly visible in MycontrollerController right? Should this method also be visible from "Mycontroller's views"? Thus, what is the interrest of including method in Helper files rather than on Controller file directly ?

Comment: Thank you for your edit Zubin, much appreciate the time your took to explain me a little bit more this machinery.
I'll try both of your solutions. :)